# TypeError: unbound method fun1() must be called with c1 instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Tags: python, inheritance

In Python, I'm implementing Inheritance. The code is as given below:

```
class c1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def fun1(self):
        print 'In Fun1'

class c2(c1):
    def __init__(self):
       c1.__init__(self)
    def fun2(self):
       c1.fun1()
       print 'In Fun2'

obj = c2()
obj.fun2()
```

When I run it, I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/madhuras/Documents/inheritance_example.py", line 15, in <module>
obj.fun2()
File "C:/Users/madhuras/Documents/inheritance_example.py", line 11, in fun2
c1.fun1()
TypeError: unbound method fun1() must be called with c1 instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Why am I getting this error? 
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You need to pass self to `c1.fun1()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call the method `fun1` of c1 using `c1.fun1()` , since its an instance method (and not a class method). You can use `super` to access `fun1()` (or even `self.fun1()` ) . Same for the `__init__()` method (though it is working currently) , better is to use `super()` for that as well.

Try the below -

```
class c1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def fun1(self):
        print 'In Fun1'

class c2(c1):
    def __init__(self):
       super(c2, self).__init__()
    def fun2(self):
       super(c2, self).fun1() #you can also do self.fun1() , but explicitly asking python to call super class's fun1 maybe better
       print 'In Fun2'

obj = c2()
obj.fun2()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the definition of fun2, where you meant to write

```
self.fun1()
```

or maybe, if you want to specifify the implementation,

```
c1.fun1(self)
```

instead of

```
c1.fun1()
```

c1 is the name of a class, not of an instance.